# How to solve the matrix equation $XX^* = A$?

Tags: matrix-equations

Is there a way to solve the matrix equation $XX^* = A$, where $X$ is a $n\times k$ unknown matrix and $A$ is a $n\times n$ positive-definite Hermite matrix?

Cholesky decomposition may be useful when $n=k$, but how about the case where $n \neq k$?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Isn't $A$ also symmetric?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is also symmetric.

Comment: Hmm, if you can assume that you compute that $\sqrt 0 =0 $ then why do you think Cholesky wouldn't be useful when $k\lt n$ (if $k \gt n$ we have no problem at all)? (If you cannot assume exactness, I think you just implement approximation below some defined $\varepsilon$. Actually I've implemented this just this way in my matrix-calculator-program)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by saying "$\sqrt 0 =0$". Could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Hmm, when you perform the Cholesky-decomposition in a case where $k \lt n$ with the most simple algorithm then you arrive after $k$ columns/rows at a residue which is ideally $0$ (practically it can be zero only if you have rational numbers so far). That leads to a cholesky-factor matrix of $n \times n$ where only $n \times k$ have "significant"/non-zero entries. Upps- if $A$ is **positive definite**, then k must equal n and cannot be smaller than n as asked in your question (I've overlooked this condition)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the Cholesky decomposition.  That is, for any such $A$, we have an $L$ such that $LL^* = A$. Now, in the case that $k>n$, construct the $n\times k$ block matrix $X$ as follows:
$$
X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
L & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $0$ here is the $n\times(k-n)$ zero matrix. We find that 
$$
XX^* = 
\begin{bmatrix}
L & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
L^* \\ 0^*
\end{bmatrix}= LL^* + 00^* = LL^* = A
$$
This will not generally be possible in the case that $k<n$. For a given symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix $A$, if $XX^* = A$ and $X$ is $n\times k$, then $k$ must be greater than or equal to the rank of $A$.